# Display HTML blocks of different height (not known in advance) on a two-columns page

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

As a picture often speaks better than words, here is a schema what I want to achieve:

[image]

So, what I try to do is placing some blocks of text on the right half or on the left half of my page. However, **I don't know in advance the height of each block** ; all I know is their width (approx. 45% of the total screen width)

The first element must be on the right half of the page, because the static element is already on the half left. However, depending of the height of block number 1, the second block must be on the left if there is room for it, else on the right.
Each block is loaded by a partial view (I'm using ASP.NET MVC)

I definitely have no idea how to achieve this, however, this is what I tried :

```
<div style="width:45%; display: inline-block">
    // My static element hard-coded
</div>

<div style="width:45%; display: inline-block">
    // My blocks
</div>
```

But I doubt this HTML structure is good, because elements will be loaded only on the 45% right.

For information, the middle separator is styled liked that :

```
.middle-separator {
    width: 1px;
    background: #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
```

I also tried playing with Bootstrap and `col-sm-4` for my blocks, but it doesn't work and Element 3, for exemple, won't be just after Element 1 but much lower.
Also, I'd prefer to avoid `<table>`and achieve this only with CSS. This is for a personal project and I'd like to do it properly.

Comment: please use css3 flex-box( http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp ) concept to achieve this

Comment: This property seems very interesting at first sight, thank you ! But is there a way to say "this element must go under the lowest block" like in my sample, just with `flex-box` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CSS

```
.card-columns {
    /*Set the column-count to how many columns you want
     *Set the column-gap to ajust the space between the cards
     */
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem
}
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100 %
}
```

Some HTML

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card"></div><!--duplicate this div and add the content for that card to it-->
</div>
```

> courtesy: bootstrap CSS

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution first, and I did this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/07k27wtj/4/
However, column-count's value is 2 but I have 4 columns. Plus, Element3 should be stuck to Element1 ; it looks like it is aligned on the bottom of the highest element, ie Element2.

Comment: you had some small errors, I fixed it for you, here is the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07k27wtj/5/

Comment: I guess it's the easiest and shortest answer, thank you so much ; I will use it !

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/dominicgan/pen/dOJQPY/

**css**

```
.elem {
  background: #eee;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(45% - 20px);
}
```

**js**

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.elem__wrapper');

var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.elem'
});
```

The [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library handles this pretty well if you don't mind some js. Otherwise the css columns works great as what @Luuk wrote.

Comment: I didn't know this library, and after a short try, it's just wonderful !! Thank you, I will probably use it in a near future

Answer (score 0):

check this out. hard-coded. i used `padding` for the of dynamic elements and a fix height for the `div` named `static` and position each div exactly the same with the image you provided for. just comment if i get you wrong.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.column1, .column2 {
  width: 45%;
}
.column1 > div, .column2 > div{
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.column2{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.static {
  height: 100px;
}

.element1 {
  padding: 100px 0 100px 0;

}

.element2 {
  padding: 150px 0 150px 0;
}

.element3 {
  padding: 35px 0 35px 0;
 
}

.element4 {
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;

}

.element5 {
  padding: 45px 0 35px 0;
}

.element6 {
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  height: 95%;
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1">
  <div class="static">
    static
  </div>

  <div class="element2">
    element2
  </div>

  <div class="element6">
    element6
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column2">
  <div class="element1">
    element1
  </div>
  <div class="element3">
    element3
  </div>
  <div class="element4">
    element4
  </div>
  <div class="element5">
    element5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider">


</div>
```

Comment: This sounds fantastic, I'll take a look deeper ! However, this implies you know if a block is on the left or the right half of the page. As I have no idea in advance if a block will be very high or not, I'd like a solution where CSS or JS do the job and decides for me if the block should be on the left or the right, depending its height and the other block's height

Comment: check the `masonry` plugin

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/amoolya93/ne9sm2kc/

```
<div class= 'parent'>
<div class="blah">
// My static element hard-coded
</div>

<div class="blah2 el1">
    // Element 1
</div>

<div class="blah2 el2">
   // Element 2 
</div>

<div class="blah2 el3">
   // Element 3
</div>

<div class="blah2 el4">
   // Element 4
</div>
</div>


.parent{
  display: flex,
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.blah{
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: inline-flex;
 }

 .blah2{
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: inline-flex
  }

.el1{
   height: 20px;
}

 .el2{
   height: 40px;
 }

 .el3{
   height: 50px;
 }

 .el4{
   height: 20px;
 }
```

Check out this fiddle where I've used flex and flex-wrap. This might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would **divide the right and the left halves of the screen into separate regions** using `<div>`

you can then slot your static element *on top* of the **left side** `<div>`

Here's a working **example**

```css
body {
  max-width: 95%;
  background: #111;
}
.columnleft {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.columnright {
  float: right;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.article {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4%;
}
.title {
  color: #aff;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
}
.content {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px 15px 30px 15px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="columnleft">
    <div id="article1" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 1</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere
        menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article2" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 2</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere
        menandri mei te, praesent <br>democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article3" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 3</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro.Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnright">
    <div id="article4" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 4</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article5" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 5</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere
        menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="article6" class="article">
      <div class="title">Headline 6</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere
        menandri mei te, praesent democritum no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit. Animal voluptaria mel te. An eum harum labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legere menandri mei te, praesent democritum
        no pro. Aliquid tractatos facilisis in eam. Odio nisl scriptorem mea ad, id alii vidisse sit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is indeed working, but this implies that you know in advance if a block will be on the right or on the left column. But unfortunately, I don't